# Springboot : deploy .jar as init.d service got 404 error

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a problem with init.d service. I followed the steps in

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

and created a jar symlink on init.d. My application is running and I can check that /var/log/myapp.log is logging springboot initialization correctly. But when a try to access my app at 8081 port I got a:

> Whitelabel Error Page 
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. 
>   Thu May 12 16:14:03 EDT 2016
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   /WEB-INF/views/login.jsp

---

### **If I run my app project direct by `java -jar target/myapp.jar` it runs correctly. And I can access at 8081 port.**

this is my actual pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.gr</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>MyApp</name>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF 8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!-- Spring Boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate validator -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- PostgreSQL -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>


<!-- JEE -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<build>
<finalName>myapp</finalName>
<plugins>
    <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

And this is my application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/myapp
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.datasource.port=5432

spring.mail.host=localhost

spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
server.port=8081
```

Anyone can help me to start a .jar as init.d service on Ubuntu?

Comment: the init.d version shouldn't do much more than starting the app via `java -jar ..`. Is there any hint in the log why it produces that 404?

Comment: Maybe check the file permissions on the jar (or jars), database, any files.  Is your init.d running as root, or did you setup a special username to run it?  If it's root, then you're all set, any other username and you'll need to check.

Comment: When I open the log at /var/log/myapp.log is the same output as running `java -jar myapp.jar`. I'm executing only one jar I changed his chmod to 777 and still the same issue. I'm starting the service logged as root user.

Comment: Try to create a myapp.conf (like you jar file) and add the DEBUG=true into it (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization) and check if the script is running like you expect.

Comment: @Sigrist Nothing special with DEBUG=true. I made tiny exemple app with the error. Could you try to reproduce? https://github.com/alephlm/spring-boot-1.3-error-executable-service Thanks

Comment: Hey @aleph, I didn't figure out why, but there is a difference when you start you test using java -jar target/gsstring.jar and ./target/gsstring.jar. If I use the first option, works as expected, if I try the executable, does not work. The second way, is how your program is called. Now we need to figure out why is not working...